Unable to use PIP within a python virtualenv, but works just fine globally
I have python 3.12 and therefore pip installed on my Mac. They were installed from python.org, NOT homebrew, however because of previous homebrew installations there seems to be an error. Whenever I run pip globally, it attempts to use homebrew's installation (which doesn't exist), and then uses the right one. Not sure why.
Additionally, my use of pip within my virtual environment seems to be broken, however when I use which pip it returns .env/bin/pip showing that it is there.
On another post, it said to start by checking python path, which after running which -a python, I get:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

The post says /usr/local/bin/python3 should be first, so maybe this is another error.
I seem to have very sloppily downloaded everything at the start, and now am trying to clean up my mess. How can I get pip to run locally within virtual environments? Ask me any specification questions please.
The return for which -a pip globally is
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip

while locally within the virtenv it is
/Users/*/Desktop/*/*/.env/bin/pip
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip

I have no idea why there are so many homebrew pips, I have uninstalled all python from homebrew and run brew cleanup and brew doctor with no results. Thank you for all your help!

Always use python -m pip notation: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/
